# Aerospike Java Client Error Message : Error -3,1,0,30000,0,2: Cluster is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, aerospike

Reading record from aerospike gives cluster is empty exception.Also the error occurs for few requests. Operations(read/write) are working fine for most of the requests but few requests randomly gives this exception

com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$InvalidNode: Error -3,1,0,30000,0,2: Cluster is empty

I am using java client version 5.1.11

Below is the code to read :

new AerospikeClient(hostName,port);

@Autowired
private AerospikeClient client;

client.get(policy, key);

Comment: Seems the client didn't connect to the cluster... Is(are) the seed(s) node(s) reachable? I am not Java developer and don't understand the @Autowired annotation, but how is the client object instantiated? You would have to have provided seed node(s) for it to find and connect to a cluster.

Comment: This is how client object is instantiated : new AerospikeClient(hostName,port);

Also cluster is empty exception occurs for few random requests.

Comment: Make sure you do check the logs to see if the client is properly reaching the cluster every time the AerospikeClient object is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if thats exactly your case, but few years ago there was a similar case of "Error -3: InvalidNode" exception on few of the requests - after investigating the user found that it was a network issue (spikes caused 200Mbps while the network channel size they had was 100Mbps).

you can read about it here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-c-client-error-code-3/4160/5